# How to check if the parameter's value of a url contains a specified text

Tags: java, url, parameters

Is there a way to check that a parameter's value of a url contains a specified text.
Let's suppose:
Specified text=Rukhmani
https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?name=Rukhmani
This is my url and I want to check that 'name' Parameter has Rukhmani

Example 2:
Here specified text is Rani
https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?name=Rukhmani
But the name parameter doesn't have Rani.

Please use Java only.

Answer (score 0):

String text = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?name=Rukhmani";

```
    if(text.contains("Rukhmani")){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

Comment: Here contains() will check for Rukhmani all over the string. But I just want to check if only 'name' parameter has Rukhmani.